# How to create a folder in WordPress if not exist yet?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, centos

I'm trying to install Wordpress on my shared host on DreamHost, using CentOS Linux.

I'm also trying to update WP theme, and it seems like DreamHost panel can't create a folder of

```
content/uploads
```

and I don't know why.
I tried using 'Media' option, but it doesn't work.

Can you advice please?

Answer (score 0):

Just upload any file with your `wp-admin` => `media` and the `uploads` folder will be automatically created.